# Getting the number of occurrences of one string in another string

Tags: java, string, indexof

I need to input a two strings, with the first one being any word and the second string being a part of the previous string and i need to output the number of times string number two occurs. So for instance:String 1 = CATSATONTHEMAT String 2 = AT. Output would be 3 because AT occurs three times in CATSATONTHEMAT. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word8 = sc.next();
    String word9 = sc.next();
    int occurences = word8.indexOf(word9);
    System.out.println(occurences);
}
```

It outputs `1` when I use this code.

Comment: `indexOf` doesn't return a count, it returns the position of the first appearance. [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Exact duplicate down to the strings of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309109/comparing-a-substring-to-a-string-in-java

Comment: @Brian That's why he's asking for help. Anyways, regex to the rescue?

Comment: Why does no one ever want to write a loop??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word8 = sc.nextLine();
    String word9 = sc.nextLine();
    int index = word8.indexOf(word9);
    sc.close();
    int occurrences = 0;
    while (index != -1) {
        occurrences++;
        word8 = word8.substring(index + 1);
        index = word8.indexOf(word9);
    }
    System.out.println("No of " + word9 + " in the input is : " + occurrences);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your scanner.

Answer (score 11):

Interesting solution:

```
public static int countOccurrences(String main, String sub) {
    return (main.length() - main.replace(sub, "").length()) / sub.length();
}
```

Basically what we're doing here is subtracting the length of `main` from the length of the string resulting from deleting all instances of `sub` in `main` - we then divide this number by the length of `sub` to determine how many occurrences of `sub` were removed, giving us our answer.

So in the end you would have something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word8 = sc.next();
    String word9 = sc.next();
    int occurrences = countOccurrences(word8, word9);
    System.out.println(occurrences);

    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: Clever :) But [`.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) would be better since it doesn't use regular expressions like `.replaceAll` does, and it has the same semantics as what you're using it as.

Comment: Thanks thats an interesting way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Why no one posts the most obvious and fast solution?

```
int occurrences(String str, String substr) {
    int occurrences = 0;
    int index = str.indexOf(substr);
    while (index != -1) {
        occurrences++;
        index = str.indexOf(substr, index + 1);
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word8 = sc.next();
    String word9 = sc.next();
    int occurences = word8.split(word9).length;
    if (word8.startsWith(word9)) occurences++;
    if (word8.endsWith(word9)) occurences++;
    System.out.println(occurences);

    sc.close();
}
```

The `startsWith` and `endsWith` are required because `split()` omits trailing empty strings.