# how to search for sentences in text file in java

Tags: java, regex

hi i'm trying to make a simple search application that fined a word or sentences(more than one word two word or more) in text file and then return the number of occurrence of this word or sentences in the text file

my test text file is:

```
hi 
hi 
hi
hello 
what is this from her what is this
i'm new 
i'm new
```

and my search function is:

```
public int search(String text,String filePath) throws IOException
{
    int count = 0;
    String line;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
           while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
             {

                if(line.toLowerCase().contains(text))
                {
                    count++;
                }

        }

    return count;
}
```

so my problem is in the test text file i can find the sentences (what is this) from the sentences (what is this from her what is this) for one time and there is tow sentences (what is this) in (what is this from her what is this) sentences.

i understand that in the code

```
if(line.toLowerCase().contains(text))
                {
                    count++;
                }
```

at the first occurrence of the (what is this) sentences it return true and continue execution and never check for another occurrence of the same sentences in the same line and return the occurrence only 1 not 2 so please help i try every thing

Comment: @aelor because the OP wants to do it in Java.

Comment: You'll have to manually count the number of occurrences of the search string in each line using another loop after reading the line. What you are really asking is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324249/getting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-one-string-in-another-string

Comment: I don't understand most of the question, but I guess you want to replace ```String.contains``` with ```StringUtils.countMatches``` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj That seems to be what he wants. His problem is that count is not getting incremented more than once since it continues to the next line after if finds the first occurrence.

Comment: Yep, as @ NeplatnyUdaj was saying, just a count += StringUtils.countMatches() should do it. With regex, the text will have to be escaped and its just too time consuming for just string constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to make it more faster.

```
public int search(String text, String filePath) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    String line;
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int fromIndex = 0;
        int index = -1;
        while ((index = line.toLowerCase().indexOf(text, fromIndex)) != -1) {
            count++;
            fromIndex = index + text.length();
        }

    }

    fr.close();
    br.close();

    return count;
}
```

Comment: it return the count = 7

Comment: `BufferedWriter` and `FileReader` are not closed. You have to close it.

Comment: Use `finally` clause to close the streams to fully ensure it that it must be closed in any case even if any exception is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

For the one-line funsies:

```
public int search(String text,String filePath) throws IOException
{
    int count = 0;
    String line;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
    while((line = br.readLine().toLowerCase()) != null)
    {
        for (; line.contains(text); line = line.replaceFirst(text, ""), count++);
    }
    return count;
}
```